# What are the steps to do code rollback in master branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-reset

I am using azure devops pipeline, I need to do a **code rollback** in my master branch,(the code in the master branch is coming from different release, e.g release/1.0.0, release/1.0.1 and tagged.)

From what I have searched, I got the following:

```
    1. git checkout master
    2. git reset --hard <tagname>
    3. git push --force origin master
```

Can anyone help, is this the best way of doing a rollback in a master branch ?
OR not.
Also, in this case the code will be overwritten with previous tags code, do we need to tag the branch again.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a *big* step to me.... do you know the consequences of rewriting history that way? If you don't then probably this is not the right path. *Normally*, if you want to take code back to how it was back in a revision, you should create a new revision following current history that takes code back.

In your case, you should do something like:

```
git checkout --detach <tagname>
git reset --soft master # set the HEAD pointer where master is
# content of files in working tree and index are like in <tagname>
git commit -m "Take code back to <tagname>"
# at this point this is a revision with no branch
# check history with git log to see if this is what you would like to have in master
# if you do like it:
git branch -f master # set master branch over here
git checkout master
git push
```

That should work.

Comment: I am a newbie in git changes, so I'll want to get sure of what you told. You mentioned to create a new branch from the existing tag, then I didn't got what the --soft command will do. Kindly help!

Comment: Nope.... you are not creating any branches for this. The first checkout makes you start working on `detached HEAD`, git will let you know once you run the command. That means you are working _without_ a branch.... you go back to a branch (master) in the last checkout. The `git reset --soft` makes git move the current branch pointer (`HEAD` in your case, because you are working in `detached HEAD`) to `master`, but the working tree and the index is not changed.... *so* you are keeping contents as it is in the tag.... but git now thinks that the revision you are on is in `master`....

Comment: ... and so if you commit, you will get a revision that _follows_ `master` and that has the contents as the tag.

Comment: @efshift0 Can I use ````git revert tag```` command for rollback ? as it will create a new commit with the previous tags code, what is your take on this ?

Comment: That will probably have very little effect because that would only revert the changes introduced between the tag parent and the tag itself.

Comment: I will require something like this code on master is tagged with 1.0.0, then 1.0.1
If I need my code of prevoius tag, ````git revert 1.0.1```` command will set the head to 1.0.0 right ? and then git push can update the master.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247882/discussion-between-priyanka-sharma-and-eftshift0).